# Unable to install the plugin for quickosm, wonder what is the next step, any idea?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, error, quickosm

Couldn't load plugin 'QuickOSM' due to an error when calling its `classFactory()` method

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\akiki\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs-rCZ.po' -> 'C:\\Users\\akiki\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs_CZ.po' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\__init__.py", line 12, in classFactory
    return QuickOSMPlugin(iface)
  File "C:\Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.extract_zip_file()
  File "C:\Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 123, in extract_zip_file
    os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\akiki\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs-rCZ.po' -> 'C:\\Users\\akiki\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs_CZ.po'


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.26.2-Buenos Aires Buenos Aires, feec3d3b12f 

Python Path:
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python39.zip
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/akiki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in QuickOSM.

I'm currently fixing it. Please upgrade your plugin later today.

Comment: It should be fixed now in 2.1.1.